# getElementsByName which name?

Tags: javascript, html, properties, getelementsbytagname

I'm creating a bunch of divs in javascript, and at a certain time I wish to delete all the divs.

My code is like this:

```
function CreateDiv(width, height, row, col){
var thisTile = document.createElement("div");
thisTile.style.position = "absolute";
thisTile.style.width = width + "px";
thisTile.style.height = height + "px";
thisTile.style.top = row*TileH + topMargin + "px";
thisTile.style.left = col*TileW + leftMargin +"px";
thisTile.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imagePath + ")";
thisTile.style.backgroundSize = imageWidth + "px " + imageHeight +"px";
thisTile.style.backgroundRepeat = "noRepeat";
thisTile.style.backgroundPosition =  "-" + col*TileW + "px -" + row*TileH + "px";
thisTile.onclick = TileClicked;
thisTile.name = "tiles";
document.body.appendChild(thisTile);
return thisTile;
}
...
var tmp = document.getElementsByName("tiles");
alert("tmp length: " + tmp.length);
for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
document.body.removeChild(tmp[i]);
```

but every time tmp is an empty array, so I can't actually remove the divs I want to,

I tried to change

```
tile.name = "tiles"
```

to

```
tile.nodeName = "tiles"
```

or

```
tile.className = "tiles"
```

but none of them worked, I just wonder which name attribute or property of an element exactly is the one in getElementsByName?

Comment: It's not really an array, it's a pseudo-array. You are looping with `for..in` but you should be looping with `for`. Are you appending the element to the DOM?

Comment: Hi @elclanrs, I used for, I just edited it.

Comment: @captain sorry but what does fiddle mean here?

Comment: Eno looks good to me... A fiddle means posting a live example so we can reproduce the problem. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/. See if you can reproduce the problem isolated from your code.

Comment: @Eno [Put your code here](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @captain I've put the key code here, thank you!

Comment: Use class names. Then you can get them by `document.getElementsByClassName` and remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `DIV` tag does not have name attribute.

check the following reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

give your divs a specific `class` and access then using :

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className)
```

Comment: So how should I get these elements here? Thank you!

Comment: @AhsanShah Thanks! It seems to work, but seems that it did not remove all of them,,,damn!

Comment: Thanks you man! I fixed it with while(tmp.length)
  document.body.removeChild(tmp[0]);

Answer (score 1):

The [`getElementsByName` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-tree-accessors) returns a list of elements with an attribute called `name`, with the given value, but only for those elements in which such an attribute is allowed by HTML specifications. And `div` is not among them.

In reality, it’s a bit more complicated. Modern browsers (including IE 10) actually implement it so that all elements with the `name` attribute *in HTML markup* are considered, even if the markup is invalid by HTML specs, like `<div name=tiles>foo</div>`. But not elements that just have the `name` property assigned to them in JavaScript. The difference is that the markup attribute also causes the information to be added into the `attributes` object.

So if you really, really wanted to use `name` here (you shouldn’t), you could replace

```
tile.name = "tiles"
```

by

```
thisTile.setAttribute("name", "tiles");
```

And it still wouldn’t work on IE 9 and older.

From the description of the purpose in the question, it seems that you should just collect an array of elements that you have added, if you later need to remove them. That is, in addition to adding an element in the document, you would append it to an array that you create, and then, when you need to delete them all, you just traverse the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code you have used the following codes including `tiles`-

```
thisTile.name = "tiles";
```

and

```
var tmp = document.getElementsByName("tiles");
```

But you have to use `tiles[]` in place of `tiles` to make `tiles` an array of elements.
That is the only mistake in your code. your code will run fine if you change these two statements.